# HTML, KnockoutJS | How do I embed a working GUI into another working GUI?

Tags: javascript, python, html, user-interface, knockout.js

So I'm trying to generate a web page with three different tabs, each with different contents.
I want the first tab to contain different HTML controls, such as radio buttons and drop down menus.

When attempting to put the two together, the GUI for the HTML controls is generated, but it seems that the HTML controls become unresponsive to any sort of input.

**Note:** I'm also using Python 2.7 with the Flask framework.

**Here is the .html code for my tabs...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    <body>  
        {% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block content %}     
        <div id="tab">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
            <ul class="ui-tab" role="tablist">
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab1" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab1' || init() == 1 }">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab2" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab2' }">Tab2</a>
                </li>
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab3" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab3' }">Tab3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab1............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab1' || init() == 1">
                <p>Tab1 Contents<br></p>
            </div>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab2............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab2'">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab3............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab3'">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
            <script>
                var TabViewModel = function(){
                    var self = this;

                    //Set href value of element
                    self.selected = ko.observable(null);

                    //initial set to show first tabpanel when loading page
                    self.init = ko.observable(1);

                    //Get href value og element
                    self.getHref = function(){
                        var target;
                        var element = event.target.hash;
                        target = element.substr(1);
                        return target;
                    };

                    //Show Tabpanel
                    self.showBlock = function(){
                        var target = self.getHref();
                        self.selected(target);
                        self.init(2);
                    };
                };

                ko.applyBindings(new TabViewModel());
            </script>

        </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the code for my table...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
        {% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        <div class='liveExample'> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>

            <div class="readout">
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
                <h3>What's in the model?</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Text value:</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: stringValue"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Password:</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: passwordValue"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Bool value:</td>
                        <td data-bind='text: booleanValue() ? "True" : "False"'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Selected option:</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: selectedOptionValue"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Multi-selected options:</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: multipleSelectedOptionValues"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">Radio button selection:</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: radioSelectedOptionValue"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <script>
                var viewModel = {
                    stringValue: ko.observable("Hello"),
                    passwordValue: ko.observable("mypass"),
                    booleanValue: ko.observable(true),
                    optionValues: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"],
                    selectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Gamma"),
                    multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(["Alpha"]),
                    radioSelectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Beta")
                };
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                </script>
            </div>

            <h3>HTML controls</h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Text value (updates on change):</td>
                    <td><input data-bind="value: stringValue" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Text value (updates on keystroke):</td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: stringValue, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Text value (multi-line):</td>
                    <td><textarea data-bind="value: stringValue"> </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" data-bind="value: passwordValue" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Checkbox:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: booleanValue" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Drop-down list:</td>
                    <td><select data-bind="options: optionValues, value: selectedOptionValue"></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Multi-select drop-down list:</td>
                    <td><select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: optionValues, selectedOptions: multipleSelectedOptionValues"></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Radio buttons:</td>
                    <td>
                        <label><input type="radio" value="Alpha" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Alpha</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" value="Beta" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Beta</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" value="Gamma" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Gamma</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
            <script>
                var viewModel = {
                    stringValue: ko.observable("Hello"),
                    passwordValue: ko.observable("mypass"),
                    booleanValue: ko.observable(true),
                    optionValues: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"],
                    selectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Gamma"),
                    multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(["Alpha"]),
                    radioSelectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Beta")
                };
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            </script>

        </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my failed attempt at putting them together...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    <body>  
        {% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block content %}     
        <div id="tab">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
            <ul class="ui-tab" role="tablist">
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab1" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab1' || init() == 1 }">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab2" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab2' }">Tab2</a>
                </li>
                <li role="tab">
                    <a href="#tab3" data-bind="click: showBlock, css: { 'active': selected() == 'tab3' }">Tab3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab1............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab1' || init() == 1">
                <p>Tab1 Contents<br></p>

                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>

                <div class='liveExample'> 
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>

                    <div class="readout">
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
                        <h3>What's in the model?</h3>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Text value:</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: stringValue"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Password:</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: passwordValue"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Bool value:</td>
                                <td data-bind='text: booleanValue() ? "True" : "False"'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Selected option:</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: selectedOptionValue"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Multi-selected options:</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: multipleSelectedOptionValues"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Radio button selection:</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: radioSelectedOptionValue"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <script>
                        var viewModel = {
                            stringValue: ko.observable("Hello"),
                            passwordValue: ko.observable("mypass"),
                            booleanValue: ko.observable(true),
                            optionValues: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"],
                            selectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Gamma"),
                            multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(["Alpha"]),
                            radioSelectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Beta")
                        };
                        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                        </script>
                    </div>

                    <h3>HTML controls</h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Text value (updates on change):</td>
                            <td><input data-bind="value: stringValue" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Text value (updates on keystroke):</td>
                            <td><input data-bind='value: stringValue, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Text value (multi-line):</td>
                            <td><textarea data-bind="value: stringValue"> </textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="password" data-bind="value: passwordValue" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Checkbox:</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: booleanValue" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Drop-down list:</td>
                            <td><select data-bind="options: optionValues, value: selectedOptionValue"></select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Multi-select drop-down list:</td>
                            <td><select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: optionValues, selectedOptions: multipleSelectedOptionValues"></select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="label">Radio buttons:</td>
                            <td>
                                <label><input type="radio" value="Alpha" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Alpha</label>
                                <label><input type="radio" value="Beta" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Beta</label>
                                <label><input type="radio" value="Gamma" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Gamma</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
                    <script>
                        var viewModel = {
                            stringValue: ko.observable("Hello"),
                            passwordValue: ko.observable("mypass"),
                            booleanValue: ko.observable(true),
                            optionValues: ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"],
                            selectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Gamma"),
                            multipleSelectedOptionValues: ko.observable(["Alpha"]),
                            radioSelectedOptionValue: ko.observable("Beta")
                        };
                        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                    </script>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab2............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab2'">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <!-- ...................................................................Tab3............................................................................... -->
            <div class="ui-tabpanel" role="tabpanel" data-bind="visible: selected() == 'tab3'">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
            <script>
                var TabViewModel = function(){
                    var self = this;

                    //Set href value of element
                    self.selected = ko.observable(null);

                    //initial set to show first tabpanel when loading page
                    self.init = ko.observable(1);

                    //Get href value og element
                    self.getHref = function(){
                        var target;
                        var element = event.target.hash;
                        target = element.substr(1);
                        return target;
                    };

                    //Show Tabpanel
                    self.showBlock = function(){
                        var target = self.getHref();
                        self.selected(target);
                        self.init(2);
                    };
                };

                ko.applyBindings(new TabViewModel());
            </script>

        </div>



        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you `applyBindings` without a specified node, knockout tries to bind to the `body` element by default. You cannot bind multiple viewmodels to the same node. Try to specify the nodes to which apply bindings for each of your viewmodels. E.g.: `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementsByClassName('ui-tabpanel')[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't seem to fix anything.

I'm getting this error when generating web page...

knockout-3.4.0.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return stringValue }"
Message: stringValue is not defined

I'm using GoogleChrome.

Comment: That's because you're binding your `TabViewModel` to the body element and all of its children. Since the viewmodel does not have a property named `stringValue`, knockout throws an error.

Comment: Please try to make your example a lot more minimal (see "[mcve]" for guidance if needed), that would make it a lot easier for us to help out.